# use barcode scan in cordova

Tags: cordova, barcode

i am Learning Cordova
i have a simple project taken from :https://www.sitepoint.com/scanning-qr-code-cordova/
but it seems not working
i used all code, installed the plugins:cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
But when the Android device starts and i push "Scan" it returns an error asking me to wriet a Json response in a popup message
this is my page, what is wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Weather</title>

  </head>
  <body>
      <div data-role="page" id="home">
          <div data-role="header">
              <h1>Home</h1>
          </div>

          <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
              <p>
                  <a target="_blank" href="javascript:scan();" style="text-decoration: none"><button>Scan</button></a>
                  <a target="_blank" href="#display" style="text-decoration: none"><button>Display Scanned Data</button></a>
              </p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div data-role="page" id="display">
          <div data-role="header">
              <a target="_blank" href="#home" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
              <h1>Display</h1>
          </div>

          <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
              <table data-role="table" data-mode="column" id="allTable" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Value</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody></tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="script/index.js"></script>-->





      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
      <script>
          if(localStorage.getItem("LocalData") == null)
{
    var data = [];
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    localStorage.setItem("LocalData", data);
}
      </script>
      <script>
          function scan()
{
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            if(!result.cancelled)
            {
                if(result.format == "QR_CODE")
                {
                    navigator.notification.prompt("Please enter name of data",  function(input){
                        var name = input.input1;
                        var value = result.text;

                        var data = localStorage.getItem("LocalData");
                        console.log(data);
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                        data[data.length] = [name, value];

                        localStorage.setItem("LocalData", JSON.stringify(data));

                        alert("Done");
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
   );
}

          </script>
      <script>

          $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#display", function() {
    $("table#allTable tbody").empty();

    var data = localStorage.getItem("LocalData");
    console.log(data);
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    var html = "";

    for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
    {
        html = html + "<tr><td>" + data[count][0] + "</td><td><a href='javascript:openURL(\"" + data[count][1] + "\")'>" + data[count][1] + "</a></td></tr>";
    }

    $("table#allTable tbody").append(html).closest("table#allTable").table("refresh").trigger("create");

});

function openURL(url)
{
    window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
}

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you paste the error trace ?

Comment: in Chrome i can see in "console" tab:
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Setting the user agent server side failed.

where can i see error trace?

Comment: In Android device run the monitor.bat in the sdk of android-tools "logcat" view

Comment: I use COrdova, maybe you're referring to "android studio" , if i run Monitor.bat nothing happens